# SSRS SQL Server 2016 Standard - Error when trying to customize security for a folder

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

We are constantly getting errors when trying to customize security on folders in SSRS 2016 standard edition.

To start, because we're using SQL Server 2016 standard, the SSRS site is currently on the same server as its associated database.

When we click on the "Customize security" button in folder security, we get an error that states, "An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details."

Below is the error we're seeing in the dump file.

Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!library!3!07/27/2023-08:28:31:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException: Wrong number of tasks found for roleBrowser, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException: An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details.;

Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!library!3!07/27/2023-08:28:31:: e ERROR: Report server dump occured. Exception: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException: An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details., Message: , Unhandled Exception: False

Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!library!3!07/27/2023-08:28:31:: e ERROR: Report server unique dump occured. Exception: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException: An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details., Message: , Unhandled Exception: False

We have tried repairing the database, changing settings in Report Configuration Manager and nothing as worked thus far. The only other item to add is that we previous tried connecting the same reporting database to a SSRS instance on a different server ..... not knowing that we could not do this with SQL Server 2016 standard edition. Also, the SSRS instance on the other machine was a newer SSRS edition so we're wondering if that messed something up in the ReportServer database we're trying to use now.

Obviously, we're expecting the customize security button to function normally allowing us to set rights for the folder as needed.

Comment: Probably when you tried to connect a different SSRS instance to the database it has littered the dbo.Users table with a bunch of new/duplicate accounts with domain/local SIDs that are invalid for the original instance. Sounds like there is some spelunking through the SSRS database in your near future... the dbo.Catalog table represents all of the SSRS items (folders, subfolders, reports, etc.), I expect you have some invalid dbo.PolicyUserRole records related to the broken folder(s)/subfolder(s) and the invalid dbo.Users records.

Comment: I would create a new instances (if possible) of both the report database and SSRS (put this on a different port) then migrate the reports over to the new instance, recreate roles etc. Then , if no errors appear on the new instance, switch them over at a convenient time. I know it's a pain but I suspect it might be faster than trying to track down what's changed/broken in the existing instance.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

We ended up restoring the ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB from previous backups.  We then executed the DeleteEncryptedContent stored procedure and restarted the SSRS services.

Voila!  The site was back to normal with fully security capabilities.